# Is there any way to "one shot" a dog creature?

Tags: penumbra

While I'm aware that penumbra is not a game where you are encouraged to be aggressive, quite the contrary, I find it very tedious to sit quietly and hide from the various dog-creatures, especially since they aren't too difficult to kill.

What I usually do is toss something heavy at them to knock them off their feet and then repeatedly whack them with the pick-axe until they are dead.

Since I have apparently gone completely insane/impatient and at times try to take on two simultaneously, I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to kill the dogs, preferably instantaneously. Perhaps some sort of elaborate physics based trap? 
Keep in mind that I have not gone much farther after using the drilling machine to access a new area of the mines and making it through the door which opens remotely from a room guarded by spiders (the one you have to race back to after opening before it closes again automatically).  I would really appreciate answers which are spoiler free considering how far I've gotten, or a fair warning if the answer does contain spoilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never found any such thing in my play through. Killing dogs is pretty simple with just the pick axe if you get your timing right. Wait for them to charge and then knock them down and keep swinging.

The game contains no super weapons of any kind (by design) and if there is a way to setup something more complicated to kill them in one shot, it would definitely only be applicable to a single dog in a single area.